# Why is Javascript the "most misunderstood language"?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, language-design

Douglas Crockford himself says so !

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html

I have been working with JS only for the past few months, with jQuery and ExtJS. Soon will get to work on Secha Touch.

I find Javascript to be highly enlightening.. What is your opinion ?

Crockford himself says that the language is not without its flaws. What flaws bother you the most ? How do you overcome them ?

Comment: The article you're linking to deals with the question of why he considers it the most misunderstood language.

Comment: In Italy we have a saying that can be roughly translated as "don't ask the innkeeper if the wine is good"... that page sounds a bit like a "nobody understands me" whine to be honest. That said, I quite like JS but try not to misuse it. But that really applies to any language.

Comment: Isn´t this something for the community wiki??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Brendan Eich (who created JavaScript) wanted to implement Lisp in the browser, but his boss told him to do something more like Java. And that having Java in the name would be good too! So he disguised his Lisp-like language in a Java-shroud.

Comment: Could you please include references to back-up your very captivating story?

Comment: I heard it from Brendan at (multiple) conferences, but it was all verbal. I'm sure there are interviews, blog posts or similar documenting it. I'll post it if I stumble upon something :)

Comment: K. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The association with Java didn't help, or rather Java Applets, back in day they were slow and likely to the crash browsers. This had a negative impact on JavaScript reputation.

Also the DOM, people associate Javascript with the DOM and its inconsistencies, fair enough the DOM is primary API for most people using Javascript but different implementations of DOM shouldnt reflect so badly on the language. Again this is an area which continues to improve.

I love the language, its so small, but you can get so much done, maybe this is because I came from a static compiled language background. Again Crockford is the better introduction before hitting the DOM space.